# How to change default thumbnail image of embedded video(not a youtube video)

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I have embedded a video in html. here is the code

```
<div >
<video width="400" controls>
    <source src="videos/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>    
</div>
```

i want to change the default thumbnail of the video. Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried searching the Internet first? Literally the first search result: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_poster.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add poster="placeholder.png" to the video tag.

```
<video width="400" height="255" poster="placeholder.png" controls>
<source src="videos/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```